# Will Chartboost block my account for clicking my own ads?

Tags: android, ios

I created a game in iOS and Android. Every day I manually click ads in it from my device.

Is this okay? Or can Chartboost block my account if I do this for a long time? I've been doing it for the last 15 days and haven't received an email from them about it yet.

Answer (score 7):

The [Chartboost TOS](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200780239) says, in part:

> You will not, and will not allow any third party to... directly or indirectly generate queries, or impressions of or clicks on ads, including without limitation Online Services Ads, through any automated, deceptive, fraudulent or other invalid means (including, but not limited to, click spam, robots, macro Online Services, and Internet agents)

It is quite likely Chartboost would consider your manually clicking on your own ads every day to be deceptive or otherwise in violation of this agreement. That means they could terminate your account or otherwise serve you with legal action.

In general this sort of thing (regularly clicking your own ads to generate artificial impressions) is a bad idea and you should not do it. They can terminate your account without notifying you:

> If You violate this Agreement, Chartboost may in its sole discretion, without notice, terminate this Agreement, or suspend or terminate the participation of Your Online Services App in all or part of the Online Services.

Just because you have not yet been *caught* yet doesn't make it okay.

Comment: Just as a prior warning, some ad companies can be very sensitive about this, I had previously worked on a site where I installed the ads and then clicked on each of the ads across the site to verify that everything was functional and it took about fifty emails just to get them to ignore that data and remove the potential click-fraud strike from the account.

Comment: so i have to wait for email or i just continue with my click ?

Comment: @DxAndroid if by "or i just continue with my click ?" you mean continuing to click your ads, **No, if you take anything away from this Q/A it would be: Don't click your own ads, it's fraud.**

Comment: but why i'm not blocked ? I earn more than 200$ from this way...

Comment: Arguing to continue doing something illegal because you haven't been caught yet is a poor argument; things like this tend to catch up with people, even with amounts as low as $200 people have in the past lost tens or hundreds of thousands in damages and legal fees, potentially even jail time depending on the nature of the violations.

Comment: Ok _/\_   ill remeber